# Proper way to install Okular

Tags: linux-mint, okular

Does someone know a proper way to install Okular on Linux Mint? I used command-line and package manager, both give same result: Okular doesn't have any icon, cannot open pdf, interface has disabled all functions and it turns off when you press it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would run:

`sudo apt-get update`

followed by

`sudo apt-get install okular`

That should do it. If you having problems beyond that then you can try

`sudo apt-get install oxygen-icon-theme*`

After that it's off to google.

Comment: You man want to read https://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rebecca_cinnamon.php